# How to change the default number of pods per node?

Tags: amazon-eks

I'm playing around with AWS EKS and I've set up a cluster with a t3.small node. Somehow the number of allocatable pods is set to 8:

```
Allocatable:
 cpu:                2
 ephemeral-storage:  19316009748
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             1902056Ki
 pods:               8
```

It seems to me that the resource request on the node is on the low side

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  310m (15%)    0 (0%)      140Mi (7%)       340Mi (18%)
```

and so I'd like to ask:

1. Is 8 a default value?
2. How can I change that?

Thanks.

Comment: After more research, I've found that it is also subject to the number of Elastic Network Interface and thus IP address. According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI, t3.small supports up to 3 network interfaces and each with up to 4 IPs (so a total of 12 IPs).  Minus the 4 kube-system containers, it should be able to provide 8 IPs for the user containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation of the max number of pods in a given node in AWS is defined by this formula:

```
Max Pods = (Maximum Network Interfaces for instance type) * (IPv4 Addresses per Interface) - 1
```

Since you used `t3.small`, the value comes down to `3 * 4 - 1 = 11`. The number 11 also depends upon the compute resources you're associating with each pod.

The list of network interfaces are listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.